# How to pass variable data in view controllers embedded in a navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Currently, I have three view controllers in my navigation stack.

In the first VC, I use a picker view to pick a time and then I use a button to pass "pickedTime var" and segue to the second VC. In the second VC, I successfully use the "pickedTime var" to show the picked time on the screen.

I ran into an issue after I tried to pass the "pickedTime var" again to the third VC. Although, the third screen loads, "pickedTime var" shows 0 on the screen instead of the pickedTime.

**First VC code:**

```
// Holds pickedTime from UIPickerView
var pickedTime = Int()

// Segue to second screen
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "showSecondScreen" {
    let controller = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
    controller.pickedTime = pickedTime
  }
}
```

**Second VC code:**

```
// Holds pickedTime passed from first VC
var pickedTime: Int()

// Show pickedTime in label
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  pickedTimeLabel.text = "\(pickedTime)"   // shows 60
}

// Segue to pop-up screen or third screen
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "segueToPopUp" {
      let controller = segue.destination as! PopUpViewController
      ...
  } else if let controller = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController {
      controller.pickedTime = pickedTime
  }
}
```

**Third VC code**

```
// Holds pickedTime passed from second VC
var pickedTime: Int()

// Show pickedTime in label
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  pickedTimeLabel.text = "\(pickedTime)"   // shows 0
}
```

Comment: Two thoughts. First, have you made sure that `controller.pickedTime = pickedTime` is bring executed? More, why are you using `var pickedTime: Int()` in any ZVC - meaning both - when you are actually supplying/passing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need to inject data to VC but instead share a Controller instance between and update instance. When the controller comes in the screen can checkout the values it needs and renders.

On your Solution:

```html
// Holds pickedTime passed from second VC

var pickedTime: Int()

// Show pickedTime in label
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  pickedTimeLabel.text = "\(pickedTime)"   // shows 0
}
```

Instead of this, you can create a new Controller called Time.swift where you save the picked time and do not need to save any variable but pas entire Object as a dependency.
Also keep in mind that you are creating a chain of dependencies which most often fail to because 'var pickedTime: Int()' will show 0 on first place

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the chain of dependencies issue with the way I was passing the picked time data. Your suggestion worked great!